# BEGIN and END Syntax Error in SQL IF Statement (SQL Server 2012)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I've been asked to create a score from a comparison of the current week  to the average of the past four weeks. (*Note* 2/2/2018 is used because the test data I have is stale)

The code was working fine until I had to wrap BEGIN and END around my statement execution to add in for updating the scoring table. I started getting the error notice on END and the ELSE that followed it. SQL Server 2012 only responds with a  "Syntax error". I've googled around for code examples but everything I found shows to do it the way I have pasted below. I'm at a lost at this point of what could be causing it. Could anyone assist?

```
Declare @HighScore as float(2) 
Set @HighScore = 35

IF (Select COUNT (Date) FROM data WHERE DATEDIFF(d,Date,'2/2/2018') <= 6 AND Category='High')
>
(Select COUNT (Date)/4 FROM data WHERE DATEDIFF(d,Date,'2/2/2018')>=7 AND DATEDIFF(d,Date,'2/2/2018')<35 AND Category='High')
BEGIN
    SET @HighScore = @HighScore - 5 
    INSERT INTO Scoring ('2/2/2018', 'High', @HIGHSCORE, 1)
END
ELSE 
    (Select COUNT (Date) FROM data WHERE DATEDIFF(d,Date,'2/2/2018')<=6 AND Category='High')
<
(Select COUNT (Date)/4 FROM data WHERE DATEDIFF(d,Date,'2/2/2018')>=7 AND DATEDIFF(d,Date,'2/2/2018')<35 AND Category='High')
BEGIN
    SET @HighScore = @HighScore + 5
    INSERT INTO Scoring ('2/2/2018', 'High', @HIGHSCORE, 1)
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
    SET @HighScore = @HighScore + 0

    INSERT INTO Scoring ('2/2/2018', 'High', @HIGHSCORE, 1)
END
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing an `IF` after the first `ELSE` (since you're doing another comparison). Also, you're missing the `VALUES` keyword in your `INSERT` statements.

EDIT: As Zohar points out in the comment below, you should really specify the column list of the target table, before the `VALUES` clause. We can't see what these are from the OP's original question, so I have used my own best guesses to fill them in.

Correcting for the errors and formatting code, I come up with:

```
DECLARE @HighScore AS FLOAT(2);

SET @HighScore = 35;

IF
    (
        SELECT COUNT(Date)FROM data WHERE DATEDIFF(d, Date, '2/2/2018') <= 6 AND Category = 'High'
    ) >
    (
        SELECT COUNT(Date) / 4
        FROM data
        WHERE DATEDIFF(d, Date, '2/2/2018') >= 7
            AND DATEDIFF(d, Date, '2/2/2018') < 35
            AND Category = 'High'
    )
BEGIN
    SET @HighScore = @HighScore - 5;

    INSERT INTO Scoring (Date, Category, Score, PlayerID) 
    VALUES ('2/2/2018', 'High', @HighScore, 1);
END;
ELSE IF
    (
        SELECT COUNT(Date)FROM data WHERE DATEDIFF(d, Date, '2/2/2018') <= 6 AND Category = 'High'
    ) <
    (
        SELECT COUNT(Date) / 4
        FROM data
        WHERE DATEDIFF(d, Date, '2/2/2018') >= 7
            AND DATEDIFF(d, Date, '2/2/2018') < 35
            AND Category = 'High'
    )
BEGIN
    SET @HighScore = @HighScore + 5;

    INSERT INTO Scoring (Date, Category, Score, PlayerID)
    VALUES ('2/2/2018', 'High', @HighScore, 1);
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @HighScore = @HighScore + 0;

    INSERT INTO Scoring (Date, Category, Score, PlayerID)
    VALUES ('2/2/2018', 'High', @HighScore, 1);
END;
```

Comment: While we are at it, it's recommended to always specify the columns list in an insert statement.

Comment: Thanks so much! That solved it! I didn't even see the missing if statement or values. I'll also specify columns, Thanks Zohar!!